# Synchronize bookmarks between PC browser and Android phone?

Tags: android

How can I synchronize bookmarks between PC browser and Android phone? If I find a URL I bookmark in my PC computer, how can I add it to the list of bookmarks in my Android devices?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about using a web application, but rather syncing browser bookmarks between a PC and an Android device. This question is more appropriate for either [su] or [android.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a sync between Google Chrome and you Android Device.

You can Google for it or [see this link](http://www.howtogeek.com/64366/how-to-sync-google-chrome-bookmarks-with-your-android-phone/)

Comment: If the phone runs Ice Cream Sandwich, then there's no need for a 3rd-party app: go to `Settings` -> `Accounts & sync` -> `Google account` and check-off `Sync Browser`.

Comment: @dnbrv: thanks! didn't know that last trick, i'm still on 2.2

Comment: I tried the chromemarks lite app, and it does fetch my bookmarks, but doesn't integrate them with the browser.